# Website down... due to sleeping MySQL connections?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I've just inherited the administration of a website, and I'm finding some problems:

When the traffic in the site peaks (it happens when our posts are featured in some distribution lists/RSS feed), the server gets busy, and then frozen (Error 502).

It's AWS hosted, and through Cloudwatch I can see that the CPU usage remains 100% for 1-1:30 hours (in normal conditions, doesn't go above 20%)...following a high traffic peak (up to 100x the average traffic during non peak moments).

- Apache requests per minute, NON PEAK: About 300
- Apache requests per minute, PEAK: About 3000

The Tomcat and Grails logs don't say much, "just" this, over and over:

> [http-bio-8080-exec-299] ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - [http-bio-8080-exec-299] Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 30 seconds, none available[size:100; busy:100; idle:0; lastwait:30000].

So I guess the problem is that when there's so much traffic, the 30 seconds time out becomes an "enemy", because there are too many users waiting to be served.

The DB config, at application level is:

> pooled = true
>
> ```
>       properties {
>
>          maxActive = 100
>          maxIdle = 25
>          minIdle = 5
>          initialSize = 5
>          minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=300000
>          timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=300000
>          numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
>          testOnBorrow=true
>          testWhileIdle=true
>          testOnReturn=true
>          validationQuery="SELECT 1"
>       }
> ```

Any recommendation on how to tweak these values?

Thanks!

UPDATE: The site is down again, and I've been able to run "top" command, and this is what I see:

```
top - 18:46:33 up  2:42,  2 users,  load average: 1.04, 1.56, 1.78
Tasks: 136 total,   1 running, 135 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 25.0%us,  0.2%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa, 28.6%hi,  0.0%si, 46.1%st
Mem:   3843124k total,  3385800k used,   457324k free,    42800k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,   681368k cached
 1340 tomcat    20   0 3611m 2.3g  11m S 61.3 64.0  51:18.60 java
 2609 root      20   0 15140 1252  916 R  0.3  0.0   0:00.14 top
    1 root      20   0 19488 1600 1284 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.88 init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.23 ksoftirqd/0
    4 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0
...
```

Comment: If cpu is at 100%, I'd suggest getting more cpu before anything else.  You can try increasing the maxActive connections but my hunch is that you're timing out simply because the CPU can't keep up with the work being thrown at it.  As a rule of thumb I start looking at adding capacity once I break 50% CPU on my systems.

Comment: Thanks yoonix! I had thought about it, but after seeing so many "no connection available" logs, I kind of focused on it. I guess I'll try to do both things...